# SHA3 bit oriented mode

Tags: sha-3

I have implemented the following code for SHA3-224 which uses "shortmessage" in bit oriented mode, the message length is 47 bits and I am not able to get correct message digest which is supposed to be "6a1cdc94a6d676d598d7dd51be9461598bd931b6a8c45d6b34dfa6bb":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include "basic_convertion.h"


#define HANDLE_ERROR(msg) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
#define HANDLE_ERROR2(msg, mdctx) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg); EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

int main()
{
    char *msg = "a1fc9771d600";

    /*Len = 47
    Msg = a1fc9771d600
    MD = 6a1cdc94a6d676d598d7dd51be9461598bd931b6a8c45d6b34dfa6bb*/


    int msg_len_byt = (strlen(msg)/2);
    int msg_len_chr = strlen(msg);//*4;
    int msg_len_bit = strlen(msg)*4;
    printf("msg_len_byt = %d\n",msg_len_byt);
    printf("msg_len_chr = %d\n",msg_len_chr);
    printf("msg_len_bit = %d\n",msg_len_bit);
    int i;
    
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
    int val;
    unsigned char * digest;
    unsigned int digest_len;
    EVP_MD *algo = NULL;

    algo = EVP_sha3_224();

    if ((mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()) == NULL) {
        HANDLE_ERROR("EVP_MD_CTX_create() error");
    }

    // initialize digest engine
    if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, algo, NULL) != 1) { // returns 1 if successful
        HANDLE_ERROR2("EVP_DigestInit_ex() error", mdctx)
    }

    //provide data to digest engine
    if (EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, msg, 47) != 1) { // returns 1 if successful
        HANDLE_ERROR2("EVP_DigestUpdate() error", mdctx)
    }

    digest_len = EVP_MD_size(algo);
    printf("digest_len = %d\n",digest_len);


    if ((digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(digest_len)) == NULL) {
        HANDLE_ERROR2("OPENSSL_malloc() error", mdctx)
    }

    
    if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, digest, &digest_len) != 1) { // returns 1 if successful
        OPENSSL_free(digest);
        HANDLE_ERROR2("EVP_DigestFinal_ex() error", mdctx)
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < digest_len; i++) {
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    }

    //OPENSSL_free(digest);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

    return 0;

}
```